# Adding a SKSpriteNode to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm stuck on something, maybe someone can help me.
I'm working on a iOS swift game (I'm a beginner iOS developer).
In the StoryBoard I've added some buttons, some views, etc.
I've added a reference (of a rectangle) in my controller like (using ctrl+drag):

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainBoardGame: UIView!
```

In my GameScene I'm creating some SKSpriteNodes like:

```
playerSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerImg")
playerSprite.position = ....
playerSprite.size = CGSize(width:...,height: ...)
self.addChild(playerSprite)
```

My problem is that this SKSpriteNodes are displayed behind the rectangle (mainBoardGame) created in my storyboard.
I've tried to add something like

```
playerSprite.zPosition = 100
```

but still the same.

I'm thinking that it would be better to add my playerSprite directly to my mainBoardGame (because it will be displayed inside of it) but I don't know how to handle a UIView and a SKSpriteNodes.
How can we add a SKSpriteNodes to a UIView ?
How to handle the z order between them ?

The main question is how to handle a UIView and a SKSpriteNode ?
Thanks.

The reason why I've build it in the storyboard is because I put some contraints in order to have a well displayed elements on each of the iPhone screen size.

Is there a way to do that in SpriteKit ?

C.C.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/75270/make-game-like-candy-crush-with-swift-tutorial-part-1

Comment: I know this tutorial but here, everything is added from the SpriteKit in the GameScene. I've added stuff in the Storyboard from the UIKit and I want to control them in my GameScene. –

Comment: sprite kit nodes can not be added to uiviews, only to other nodes

Answer (score 2):

SpriteKit does not play nicely with subviews. SKScene wants to occupy a view entirely, so the high-performance 2D game engine can work its magic.

Why not just create your game board within your scene, and have the enclosing view occupy constraints? It's harder to provide a more specific answer without more detailed code examples.